# Python Library recommendation for online traveling salesperson problem animation

Tags: python, animation

I'm fairly new at Python and do not have experiences with any library other than matplotlib for graphs. I want to implement the online traveling salesperson problem with a single traveling object and multiple fixed nodes, where the nodes randomly generate messages at runtime which the traveling object is then required to read by going to the respective node.

Which library can be used to provide a clean view for such a task so that the random behavior of the nodes along with their respective 2d locations can be visualized in an animation?

Answer (score 0):

[Manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) is a python animation engine for explanatory math videos that is used by the youtuber 3Blue1Brown.

I have no personal experience with it so I cant vouch for its ease of use, but this seems to fit exactly what you are looking for